# How to delete first date duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have this df:

```
             time
0 2022-07-28 13:35:00
1 2022-07-28 13:35:15
2 2022-07-28 13:35:15
3 2022-07-28 13:35:30
4 2022-07-28 13:35:30
```

I need to remove the first .time duplicate, so the final result will be like this:

```
             time
0 2022-07-28 13:35:00

2 2022-07-28 13:35:15

4 2022-07-28 13:35:30
```

sample  code:

```
tbl2 = {"time" :["2022-07-28 13:35:00", "2022-07-28 13:35:15", "2022-07-28 13:35:15",
            "2022-07-28 13:35:30", "2022-07-28 13:35:30"]}



df2 = pd.DataFrame(tbl2)

df2.time = pd.to_datetime(df2.time)
```

Comment: try this  `df2.time.drop_duplicates(keep='last')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution above works fine as long as you only have a max of 1 duplicate (i.e. each time occurs at most twice). However, if you have more duplicates, you can use the approach below:

```
# Make sure that time data is sorted
df2.sort_values(by="time", inplace=True)

# Add a rownumber per time group and a count of rows per group
df2["time_rownum"] = df2.groupby("time").cumcount() + 1
df2["time_count"] = df2.groupby("time")["time_rownum"].transform('max')

# Filter
mask = (df2["time_count"] == 1) | ((df2["time_rownum"] > 1) & ((df2["time_count"] > 1)))
df2 = df2.loc[mask, ["time"]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems better, what if df2 has more columns?

Comment: df2.loc[mask, ["time"]] gives me 13k rows, but when i print df2 i get 20k rows (it did not remove them)

Comment: yes so you would need to assign like so: `df2 = df2.loc[mask, ["time"]]` - I will update the solution.

Comment: and the extra columns shouldn't make a difference, to answer your other question

Comment: ok thanks, in my original df i have a df2 with multiple columns, when i print (df2) i get only the "time" column, how can i "get" the original dataframe with dropped rows?

Comment: Ah OK, so you can replace the last line in the answer with `df2 = df2[mask]`, because in the original, I was explicitly only selecting the `time` column

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop_duplicates` and keep the `last` value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"time" :["2022-07-28 13:35:00", "2022-07-28 13:35:15", "2022-07-28 13:35:15", "2022-07-28 13:35:30", "2022-07-28 13:35:30"]})
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df.drop_duplicates(keep='last', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                 time
0 2022-07-28 13:35:00
2 2022-07-28 13:35:15
4 2022-07-28 13:35:30
```